# Accessing JSON value via jq using variable key

Tags: json, jq

I have a file with JSON like:
test.json

```
{
    "NUTS|/nuts/2010": {
        "type": "small",
        "mfg": "TSQQ",
        "colors": []
    }
}
```

I am getting "NUTS|/nuts/2010" from outside and I am storing it in a shell variable. I am trying to use the below snippet and using jq util, but I am not able to access the corresponding json against the above key.

test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

NUTS_PATH="NUTS|/nuts/2010" #Storing in shell variable
INPUT_FILE="test.json"
RESULT=($(jq -r --arg NUTS_PATH_ALIAS "$NUTS_PATH" '.[$NUTS_PATH_ALIAS]' $INPUT_FILE))

echo "Result: $RESULT"
echo $RESULT > item.json
```

When I run this, I am getting:

```
Result: {
```

But it should return

```
{
        "type": "small",
        "mfg": "TSQQ",
        "colors": []
    }
```

Any help. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem isn't associated with `jq` at all. What you have should work fine, but the issue is with the assignment of the result to an *array* when you might have intended to store it in a *variable*

```sh
RESULT=($(jq -r --arg NUTS_PATH_ALIAS "$NUTS_PATH" '.[$NUTS_PATH_ALIAS]' $INPUT_FILE))
#     ^^^ =( .. ) result is stored into an array
```

A variable like expansion of an array of form `$RESULT` refers to element at index 0, i.e. `${RESULT[0]}`, which contains the `{` character of the raw JSON output

You should ideally be doing

```sh
RESULT="$(jq -r --arg NUTS_PATH_ALIAS "$NUTS_PATH" '.[$NUTS_PATH_ALIAS]' "$INPUT_FILE")"
```

Comment: Thanks @Inian it helps. Working like charm.

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer

Comment: @SiHA Yes indeed

Answer (score 1):

I always end up swearing at jq, too!

For me, this jq query works:

```
$ jq '.["NUTS|/nuts/2010"]' test.json
{
  "type": "small",
  "mfg": "TSQQ",
  "colors": []
}
```

However, because you've got pipes and slashes in your string, the variable quoting gets a bit funny.

```
NUTS_PATH='"NUTS|/nuts/2010"' #Note the two sets of quotes
INPUT_FILE="test.json"
RESULT=$(jq ".[$NUTS_PATH]" $INPUT_FILE)

echo "Result: $RESULT"

Result: {
  "type": "small",
  "mfg": "TSQQ",
  "colors": []
}
```

Disclaimer, I'm not a BASH expert, there may (probably is) be a better way to sort out the quoting

Comment: Thanks @SiHa.  Your suggestion works. Also, in addition to above, using escape chars, we can get the same result. 
A="NUTS"
B="/nuts/2010"
NUTS_PATH0="\"${A}|${B}\""
RESULT=$(jq ".[$NUTS_PATH0]" $INPUT_FILE)